# How to create a singleton object using std::unique_ptr of a class with private destructor?

Tags: c++, singleton

How to create a singleton class using `std::unique_ptr`? My current implementation makes use of a static function `get_instance()` for initializing the `std::unique_ptr`. I'm using `std::once_flag` and `std::call_once` for thread safety inside `get_instance()`.

The problem I'm facing is I want to make the destructor private, but I'm getting a compiler error since `std::unique_ptr` can't access the private destructor.

This is my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>

class A final {
    A() {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
    }

    inline static std::unique_ptr<A> instance;
    inline static std::once_flag instance_flag;
    inline static std::once_flag destruct_flag;

public:
    static std::unique_ptr<A>& get_instance() {
        std::call_once(instance_flag, [] () {
            instance.reset(new A()); 
        });

        return instance;
    }

    static void release_instance() {
        std::call_once(destruct_flag, [] () {
            instance.release();
        });
    }
};

int main() {
    A::get_instance();
    A::release_instance();
}
```

Comment: Why do you use dynamic storage for a singleton? Why not `static A instance{}; return instance;`?

Comment: @eerorika I know about Scott Meyer's Singleton solution. I'm just trying using `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: A Meyers singleton can just return a std::unique_ptr&. I just don't see the added benefit (unless it is for expirimentation and self-education)

Comment: @PepijnKramer the only reason I made `std::unique_ptr` a class member is for releasing the instance manually, like I did in my `main` function.

Comment: @Harry "*`std::unique_ptr` can't access the private destructor*" - Have you tried making `unique_ptr` be a `friend` of `A`?

Comment: @Harry `I'm just trying using std::unique_ptr` And my question is: **Why** are you using it (and dynamic storage in general)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried it by adding`friend class std::unique_ptr<A>;`, but still getting same error

Comment: @Harry my mistake, it is not `std::unique_ptr` that needs to be a friend, but rather its `deleter` instead, in this case `std::default_delete<A>`

Comment: @JaMIT Yes, that one of the issues which I'm facing and I was thinking of posting it. Can you tell me how to avoid that?